# sqlsrv_fetch_object() not returning results

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I have a simple SELECT statement, an optional WHERE clause, and an ORDER BY however while looping through sqlsrv_fetch_object() I am not getting any records:

```
if (!$conn) 
{
    echo "no connection!\n";
}
$data = array();
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT lineid, ord_num, prod_num, description, prod_type, style, color, sizetype, qty1, qty2, qty3, qty4, qty5, qty6, qty7, qty8, qty9, qty10, qty11, qty12, qty13, qty14, qty15, ext_id, decoration1, design1, iposition1, cccode1, decoration2, design2, iposition2, cccode2, decoration3, design3, iposition3, cccode3, '', design4, iposition4, cccode4, decoration5, design5, iposition5, cccode5, decoration6, design6, iposition6, cccode6, decoration7, design7, iposition7, cccode7, last_mod FROM DataLIVE.dbo.sodetail ";
if ($last_run_date)
{
    $qry .= "WHERE last_mod > '" . $last_run_date . "' "; 
}
$qry .= "ORDER BY last_mod ASC";
fwrite($fp, $qry . "\n");

if ($st = sqlsrv_query($conn, $qry))
{

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($st))
    {
        $row->last_mod      = $row->last_mod->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        fwrite($fp, "Last Mod::: " . $row->last_mod . "\n");
        $data[]     = $row;
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($st);
    unset($row, $st);
}
else 
{
    $sqlerr = sqlsrv_errors();
    foreach ($sqlerr as $key)
    {
        foreach ($key as $col => $val)
        {
            echo "Error Key: " . $col . "\nError Msg: " . $val . "\n";
            fwrite($fp, "Error Key: " . $col . "\nError Msg: " . $val . "\n");
        }
    }

    $data = FALSE;
}
return $data;
```

I don't know why sqlsrv_fetch_object() is not returning anything. Also, I can copy and paste the query directly into SQL Server Studio from the log I'm writing, it parses fine. There is nothing in my log file where I am writing out the last_mod date in the while loop.

I posted this with a slightly different question a few minutes ago and someone suggested to remove the selection of an empty string in the SELECT statement, but I need that empty string placeholder there where it is.

Comment: Do you get any output at all? Maybe putting some unconditional output into the "good"-branch will help sheding some light on the issue. `if ($st = sqlsrv_query($conn, $qry))
{ echo '<p>And here are the results:</p>'; [...] echo '<p>Done.</p>'; sqlsrv_free_stmt($st);`

Comment: It appears that the sqlsrv_fetch functions don't like an empty placeholder in the SELECT statement. After I changed SELECT column1, column2, '', column4... to SELECT column1, column2, '' AS column3, column4... It worked fine.

Comment: What if you give it a name: `SELECT '' as my_empty_field`

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did as you can see in my previous comment. It made sense after I thought about it because sqlsrv_fetch_object can't assign a property to the object since the empty string had no name.

Comment: And that didn't show up in the branch starting with `$sqlerr = sqlsrv_errors();` ? Wow.